# Object following mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a simple pygame application where an object follows the mouse.
However, I noticed that there is some delay of 1/2 frames between the object and the mouse motion, even if frames are not limited.
This is the code:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

class MainLoop(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
        self.clock=pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps=60
        self.square=pygame.Rect(0,0,64,64)

    def eventloop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                self.square.center=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((255,255,255))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,(0,0,0),self.square,1)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            self.eventloop()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainLoop()
    app.loop()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related with how your mouse cursor is rendered. Basically you're using your operating system's mouse rendering(I think this is also called "hardware mouse/cursor") which updates it's position and renders more frequently than your software's frame rate.

If you disable hardware mouse/cursor rendering and put a mouse icon manually you'll realize that your rectangle and mouse positions will be updated without delays in between. (I think this is obvious but I still wanted to mention)